# SD card planted in my pocket

Tags: malware, forensics

Today, I found a SD card in my pocket. I've never seen it before and am nearly certain I didn't put it there myself. My suspicion is that someone stealthily planted it there while I was walking through a public space.

I'm just wondering, as someone who is fairly knowledgeable about computers but not particularly familiar  with the security world, if anyone has ever heard of anything like this before. My theory was that it might contain some malware / ransomware that would infect a PC into which the drive was inserted, but that's mainly based on seeing something similar in an episode of Mr. Robot.

I feel like the safest action would be to simply destroy the thing, but for curiosity's sake, is there some way to find out what's actually on it? I was thinking maybe disconnecting my main hard drive and booting a Linux live CD... or could it screw with my system at a lower level even then?

Comment: Or use a virtual machine and then nuke the virtual machine

Comment: Disconnect your main drive and boot a Linux live distro. I don't believe anyone would get an advanced malware on a SD, and throw it away in the pocket of some random guy on the subway. You (or someone from your family) may later recognize it as a long lost SD card...

Comment: Darn, our spy controller gave the SD card with instructions to the wrong guy _again_!

Answer (score 2):

This is a very odd situation but I would take the following steps to understand what is on the card:

- Create a clean VM (Windows since this is the most popular OS and if there is malware it is probably compatible with Windows) and disconnect it from the host in every way
- Get a SD Card reader and mount it to the VM
- Insert the SD Card and see what's on it

If you have a PC you don't care about you an use that too.
But again, the chances of you finding malware on it are low as this is a lot of effort for an attack (unless you are targeted, which I assume you are not).

Answer (score -1):

"target evaluation" is the first phase of hacking, so you should ask yourself *"why would someone try to hack me?"* . if you are an student , it could be love letter rather than a sinister hacker! BTW 
if someone is targeting you, he/she has detailed plan. you can block the hacker (if it's not an illusion) using two methods :

 
**safer/harder way:** using vm machine as *'Bubble Hacker'*  mentioned in answers. or using linux live boot. 
**smart/easy way:** since the hacker has detailed plan, he probably know you and your system. so simply break your habits!! if you are a mac user, insert SD into windows , or if you are a windows person , use a linux! malware/virus inside the SD is prepared for you and your system. changing OS is an unpredicted move for hacker. you can use your family or friends laptop  **just be sure to disable java and JRE on this system**  (cause only java programs are platform independent)

Comment: "cause only java programs are platform independent" - or Python, PHP and doubtless many other interpreted languages.

Comment: please tell me where do u run PHP? it should be run by a web server. we are talking about virus/malware not programing a website! so it's not "best language"  debate.